# How to implement cholesky decomposition using numpy efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement efficient realization of cholesky decomposition. Naive code looks like

```
import numpy as np
def cholesky(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    L = np.zeros_like(A)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            s = 0
            for k in range(j):
                s += L[i][k] * L[j][k]

            if (i == j):
                L[i][j] = (A[i][i] - s) ** 0.5
            else:
                L[i][j] = (1.0 / L[j][j] * (A[i][j] - s))
    return L
```

I wonder if there is a way to make it more efficient. E.g vectorize it?

Comment: Do you really need to do this on your own? It's already implemented in `scipy`

Comment: @mathfux, yes, the key idea is effective implementation and usage of numpy arrays power

Comment: Does it *have* to be `numpy`? I would suggest using `numba`

Comment: @dankal444, I meant numpy and numpy-like libraries in terms of syntax. I want to avoid naive for loops and use vectorization, slicing, etc.

Comment: @Nourless Just a remainder: usage of loops is not a naive approach while using `numba`. In the most cases it's much faster than any kind of  `numpy` methods. Btw, I'm quite interested in `numpy` approach, rather as an educational demo.

Answer (score 4):

This is not vectorized, but for matrix of size 100 it is ~1000x faster:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('float64[:, :](float64[:, :])')
def cholesky_numba(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    L = np.zeros_like(A)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            s = 0
            for k in range(j):
                s += L[i][k] * L[j][k]

            if (i == j):
                L[i][j] = (A[i][i] - s) ** 0.5
            else:
                L[i][j] = (1.0 / L[j][j] * (A[i][j] - s))
    return L
```